# How to create RadioButton component in ReactXP?

Tags: reactjs, reactxp

I have no idea how to create the component which is not available in react-xp package? Any clue or idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `radio` or `toggle` component - you have to create a new one by you, also it has to be valid for WEB and for `react-native`.